# align text input boxes to right of div

Tags: html, css, forms, text, input

I am trying to align the text inputs to the edge of .formColumn2 so they all line up together nicely but am not sure how to do so. I have tried margin-right:0 and tried margin-left but that extends the .formColumn2 div which I don't want. I'd also like to avoid float right if possible.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/43w8G/

CSS

```
.bookingForm {
height:450px;
background-color: #D3412A;
}

.bookingForm img {
width:200px;
margin:90px 0 0 170px;
}

form{
padding:20px 0 0 70px;
margin-left: 10%;
color:#fff;
}

.bookingForm .formColumn1,
.bookingForm .formColumn2{
float:left;
}

.bookingForm .formColumn2 {
margin-left: 50px;
}

.bookingForm .formColumn2 input{
 margin-right:0;
}

 select,input,textarea {
 width:200px;
 margin:8px 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don’t want to float them, then use `text-align`.

Comment: I tried applying text-align to .formColumn2 input{
 text-align:right;
} but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a width of the label.

```
.formColumn2 label {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That will set the labels to a fixed width making the inputs line up.

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eF3am/)

Answer (score 0):

This works, a little bit hackish, but this is another way to do it.

```
.bookingForm .formColumn2 input {
    margin-right:0;
    float:right;
}
.bookingForm .formColumn2 label {
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emersive/Jwvq6/